# Returning vertex and edge properties in one query

Tags: orientdb

I'm working with OrientDb 3.0.1.

Assume the following schema:

```
CREATE CLASS Product EXTENDS V;
CREATE PROPERTY Product.number STRING (MANDATORY, NOTNULL);

CREATE CLASS Object3D EXTENDS V;
CREATE PROPERTY Object3D.path STRING (NOTNULL);

CREATE CLASS has_Object3D EXTENDS E;
CREATE PROPERTY has_Object3D.in LINK Object3D (MANDATORY, NOTNULL);
CREATE PROPERTY has_Object3D.out LINK V (MANDATORY, NOTNULL);
CREATE PROPERTY has_Object3D.translation EMBEDDEDLIST INTEGER (MANDATORY, NOTNULL);
```

And some data like:

```
INSERT INTO Product (number) VALUES
('1'), ('2'), ('3');

INSERT INTO Object3D (path) VALUES
("path1"), ("path2"), ("path3");

CREATE EDGE has_Object3D
FROM (SELECT FROM Product WHERE number = '1')
TO (SELECT FROM Object3D WHERE path = 'path1')
SET translation = [0, 0, 0];
```

**Question**: Knowing only the product number, how can I fetch properties **both** from `Object3D` vertex and corresponding `has_Object3D` edge in one query?

Something like this (not working):

```
SELECT
  expand(out('has_Object3D')),
  outE('has_Object3D').translation
FROM Product
WHERE number = '1';
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select out('has_Object3D').path as path, outE('has_Object3D').translation as translation from Product where number = "1"
```

this is the output:

```
+----+-------+-----------+
|#   |path   |translation|
+----+-------+-----------+
|0   |[path1]|[[0,0,0]]  |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

**UPDATE**

```
select out('has_Object3D').path as path, outE('has_Object3D').translation as translation from Product where number = "1" unwind path, translation
```

this is the output:

```
+----+-----+-----------+
|#   |path |translation|
+----+-----+-----------+
|0   |path1|[0,0,0]    |
+----+-----+-----------+
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve one result pair per row - not in the array?

Comment: @Khozzy I've update the answer. Let me know if helps

Comment: It works - but I posted more generic query also as the answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

However the answer posted by @michela-bonizzi works there might be issues when there is more than one edge between vertices.

The following query is more generic and also works as expected.

```
MATCH {class: has_Object3D, as: e}.outV() {where: (number = '1')}
RETURN 
  e.inV().path AS `path`,
  e.translation AS `translation`
```